Atttempting to insert python matplotlib plot into a Word document table
My module creates a Word document and then  creates a 3 column table in the document. The module then calls a function from another module which produces a trapezoid from randomly created vertices plotted in a Cartesian grid.
I am getting error message AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'seek'. Traceback is provided at the end.
The finished product should look something like this which I produced manually:
The main module is:
import os
import random
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches
from datetime import datetime
from docx.oxml import OxmlElement, ns
import Trapezoid_in_Cartesian_Grid_1
from PIL import Image


doc = Document()

tbl = doc.add_table(rows=1, cols=0)
tbl.add_column(width=Inches(0.4))
tbl.add_column(width=Inches(3.0))
tbl.add_column(width=Inches(3.0))

for i in range(10):
    a = random.randint(-8,8)
    b = random.randint(-8,8)
    h = random.randint(-3,3)
    k = random.randint(-3,3)
    fig = Trapezoid_in_Cartesian_Grid_1.ReflectTrap01OverXaxis(a,b,h,k)
    
    row = tbl.add_row()
    cell1 = tbl.cell(i,0)
    cell1.text = str(i+1) + "."
    cell2 = tbl.cell(i,1) 
    cell2.text = "Reflect the figure over the y-axis."
    cell3 = tbl.cell(i,2)
    paragraph = tbl.rows[0].cells[2].paragraphs[0]
    run = paragraph.add_run()
    run.add_picture(fig, width=Inches(3.0), height=Inches(3.0))
   
# get current date and time and convert to string
current_datetime = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S")
print("Current date & time : ", current_datetime)
str_current_datetime = str(current_datetime)
 
# create a file object along with extension
file_name = "WS_Proj " + str_current_datetime
header = doc.sections[0].header
header.paragraphs[0].text = file_name
footer = doc.sections[0].footer

doc.save(file_name + ".docx")

The module (with function) which is called is
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.path import Path
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
from docx.shared import Inches
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import random

a = random.randint(-8,8)
b = random.randint(-8,8)
h = random.randint(1,5)
k = random.randint(1,5)

current_datetime = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S")
str_current_datetime = str(current_datetime)

def ReflectTrap01OverXaxis(a,b,h,k):
       
   #Creates a polygon with certain vertices (verts1)
    verts1 = [(a,b),(a+h,b),(a+h,b-k),(a,b-k+1),(a,b)]
    codes1 = [Path.MOVETO, Path.LINETO, Path.LINETO, Path.LINETO, Path.CLOSEPOLY]
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    path1 = Path(verts1, codes1)
    patch1 = patches.PathPatch(path1, edgecolor = "black", facecolor = "None", lw=1, zorder = 3)
    ax.add_patch(patch1)
    
   #Sets x and y axes
    ax.set_xlim(-12,12)
    ax.set_ylim(-12,12)
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.tick_params(labelsize = 6)
    plt.xlabel(None, fontsize = 7)
   #Determines the size of the plot
    plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [3.0,3.0]
    
    plt.axhline(color = "black")
    plt.axvline(color = "black")
    
    ax.grid(which = "both",color = "black", linewidth=0.4)
    ax.minorticks_on()
    
   #Creates a unique file name with date and time
    current_datetime = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S")
    str_current_datetime = str(current_datetime)
    file_name = "fig1 " + str_current_datetime
    plt.savefig(file_name,dpi = 1200 ,format = "jpg")
    
    return fig

    File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File c:\users\barry\.spyder-py3\createtablewithspecificdimensions.py:40
    run.add_picture(fig, width=Inches(3.0), height=Inches(3.0))

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\docx\text\run.py:79 in add_picture
    inline = self.part.new_pic_inline(image_path_or_stream, width, height)

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\docx\parts\story.py:71 in new_pic_inline
    rId, image = self.get_or_add_image(image_descriptor)

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\docx\parts\story.py:37 in get_or_add_image
    image_part = package.get_or_add_image_part(image_descriptor)

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\docx\package.py:31 in get_or_add_image_part
    return self.image_parts.get_or_add_image_part(image_descriptor)

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\docx\package.py:74 in get_or_add_image_part
    image = Image.from_file(image_descriptor)

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\docx\image\image.py:49 in from_file
    stream.seek(0)

AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'seek'

Thank you for any assistance.

Return the path to the saved file, rather than the Figure from the function https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#docx.text.run.Run.add_picture

@OneCricketeer I returned the image path and the module is behaving as expected, but now "The picture cannot be displayed" pops up in the word document and "Word found unreadable content." I appreciate your patience.

Apparently MS Word has trouble if an image header is missing or corrupted. Merely adding the file extension, such as "jpeg" is not enough. I found this code snippet online which "fixes" the header. I placed this snippet in the for loop of my main module, right after calling ReflectTrap01OverXaxis().
def image_to_jpg(image_path):
path = Path(image_path)
if path.suffix not in {'.jpg', '.png', '.jfif', '.exif', '.gif', '.tiff', '.bmp'}:
    jpg_image_path = f'{path.parent / path.stem}_result.jpg'
    Image.open(image_path).convert('RGB').save(jpg_image_path)
    return jpg_image_path
return image_path

My program is now behaving as it should.
